# using enum to store current state class in swift

Tags: swift

I have these two classes:

```
class State1 {
    static func getInfo() -> String {
        return "sometext1"
    }
}

class State2 {
    static func getInfo() -> String {
        return "sometext2"
    }
}
```

I also have this enum for states:

```
enum State {
    case state1
    case state2

    var instance: Any {
        switch self {
        case .state1:
            return State1.self
        case .state2:
            return State2.self
        }
    }
}
```

And I am trying to store current state in a variable and call the class' method based on the enum:

```
var currentState = State.state1.instance
print(currentState) //prints State1

currentState.getInfo() //currentState is of type Any so not possible to call State1 methods
```

Any idea how to get around this?

Comment: If you have classes, won’t be better to use superclass?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your core question, you could use **enums with associated values** for better case handling.

> #### Associated Values
>
> ...
>
> You can define Swift enumerations to store associated values of any
>   given type, and the value types can be different for each case of the
>   enumeration if needed. Enumerations similar to these are known as
>   discriminated unions, tagged unions, or variants in other programming
>   languages.
>
> <sub>Ref: [Swift Documentation on Enums](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Enumerations.html)</sub>

---

#### Example:

```
enum State {
    case state1(_ state: State1.Type)
    case state2(_ state: State2.Type)
}

let currentState = State.state1(State1.self)

//Using switch for handling multiple cases
switch currentState {
case .state1(let state):
    state.getInfo()
case .state2(let state):
    state.getInfo()
}

//Using if for handling single cases 
if case State.state1(let state) = currentState {
    state.getInfo()
}
```

---

More on Enums with Associated Values here:

- [Swift Documentation on Enums](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Enumerations.html)<sup>(Read Sub-Topic: Associated Values)</sup>
- [Advanced and Practical Enum usage in Swift](https://appventure.me/2015/10/17/advanced-practical-enum-examples)

Answer (score 3):

If the classes do not do much, I would just put the member functions in the enum

```
enum State{
    case state1
    case state2

    func getInfo() -> String
    {
        switch self
        {
        case .state1:
            return "sometext1"
        case .state2:
            return "sometext2"
        }
    }
}


var currentState = State.state1
print(currentState)
print(currentState.getInfo())
```

If you really want the States have their own class, you have to declare them extend the same superclass or implement the same protocol, and use that superclass/protocol in the enum.

```
protocol StateProtocol
{
    static func getInfo() -> String
}

class State1 : StateProtocol
{
    static func getInfo() -> String {
        return "sometext1"
    }
}

class State2 : StateProtocol
{
    static func getInfo() -> String {
        return "sometext2"
    }
}

enum State {

    case state1
    case state2

    var instance: StateProtocol.Type {
        switch self {
        case .state1:
            return State1.self
        case .state2:
            return State2.self
        }
    }
}

var currentState = State.state1.instance
print(currentState) //prints State1
print(currentState.getInfo())
```

Though I am not quite comfortable with returning the `Type` of the class just to use its static method.

It is much more logical to use the State class as instances instead of just using it's static method. (Why would you name the variable instance while it is not an instance?)

```
class StateClass
{
    func getInfo() -> String
    {
        return "default text"
    }

}

class State1 : StateClass
{
    override func getInfo() -> String
    {
        return "sometext1"
    }

    static let instance = State1()
}

class State2 : StateClass
{
    override func getInfo() -> String
    {
        return "sometext2"
    }

    static let instance = State2()
}

enum State{
    case state1
    case state2

    var instance : StateClass
    {
        switch self{
        case .state1:
            return State1.instance
        case .state2:
            return State2.instance
        }
    }
}

var currentState = State.state1.instance
print(currentState)
print(currentState.getInfo())
```